# What additional configs are needed to allow Capistrano to access Vagrant VM beyond those needed to ssh in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, vagrant, capistrano

Using latest Capistrano (v3.11.0), Vagrant (v2.1.2), and Rails (v5.2.0).

By appending the output of `vagrant ssh-config` to ~/.ssh/config, I am able to ssh into the VM with a "real" ssh session (not just via `vagrant ssh`):

devbox $ ssh vagrant@myvm

However, Capistrano is unable to connect. For instance, using a stock Capistrano task fails with this SSHKit error:

```
devbox $ cap staging git:check

Traceback (most recent call last):
<stuff snipped>

cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as vagrant@cvong: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Caused by:
SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I suspect that the problem is due to how the ssh session uses an interactive, login session while Capistrano uses a non-interactive, non-login session (https://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/). Presumably the ssh session picks up the VM's ssh configs from ~/.ssh/config while Capistrano does not, so Capistrano cannot find the VM. Or is there some other explanation?

So how do I feed the necessary configs into Capistrano, and what are they? The Capistrano docs page above explains the problem but doesn't say what to do about it. Further I can't seem to find docs about the ssh_options that can be specified when defining a server in Capistrano, which is where it seems these configs should go.

Here is the server definition in my_rails_app/config/deploy/staging.rb:

```
server "myvm",
  user: 'vagrant',
  roles: %w{app db web},
  primary: true,
  ssh_options: {
    forward_agent: true,
    keys: ['~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key'],
    port: '2222',
    host_name: 'myvm'
  }
```

Capistrano is obviously finding the VM's name since "vagrant@myvm" appears in the SSHKit error. However, it seems like something is missing in the ssh_options section so that Capistrano can't log in. Clearly this appears to Just Work for most people, so what stupid error am I making?

Many thanks indeed for any pointers!

Comment: Would mark this "answered" if I could. Never could get this to work with the default vagrant user, but after setting up a regular user along with working SSH keys -- and crucially by deleting the server definition and simply using the role syntax, Capistrano no longer fails in the same fashion to reach the Vagrant VM. Less is more apparently in Capistrano configs.

Comment: Next problem is the fact that Capistrano 3 no longer supports push from a local git repository the way that Capistrano 2 used to, but that's another fight for another day.